# Full Text Search on MySQL : Perform search by multiple words in one DB table

Tags: mysql, algorithm, search, full-text-search

I have the User DB table:

```
|firstname|lastname|username|Country|id|
------------------------------------------------
|Ricky    |Jonh    |rjohn   |USA    |1 |
|Mery     |Cris    |mcris   |USA    |2 |
|Ricky    |Cris    |rcris   |Germany|3 |
|Michacle |Ricky   |mricky  |USA    |4 |
|Michacle |Jonh    |john    |USA    |5 |
```

In case, the user types:

- "Ricky" - search should return 3 records (1,3,4)
- "Ricky USA" - should return 2 records (because only the first and the third record have these words on their columns)
- "Ricky John USA" - return only the first record.

So search should return records where each word of search should be in one record but can be on the different columns.

Can someone share an approach how to implement such search on MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [O. Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones)

Here is a solution

```
  SELECT *,
  MATCH (firstname, lastname, username, Country) 
         AGAINST ('+Ricky +Cris +Germany' IN boolean MODE) AS score
  FROM user 
  WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, username, Country)
         AGAINST ('+Ricky +Cris +Germany' IN boolean MODE)
  ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This involves setting up and then using a FULLTEXT index. This sets up the index (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2E7ep7eos8wNWUNq6VTCEv/0):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX textindex ON user (firstname, lastname, username, country);
```

And this uses it. It shows the FULLTEXT score for each record, and orders them highest score first.

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH (firstname, lastname, username, Country)
         AGAINST ('Ricky Cris Germany' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
  FROM user 
 WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, username, Country)
         AGAINST ('Ricky Cris Germany' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

FULLTEXT in natural language mode is inherently fuzzy. It's designed to show candidate search results to a user so she can select a relevant one. It likes to return a lot of "false positive" rows, hopefully with lower scores than the real rows.  **Edit** FULLTEXT works like internet search engines: it displays several results and makes a best-efforts attempt to rank them by relevance. Then it relies on the user to choose the desired result. It's too much to expect of FULLTEXT that it will remove undesired items from its result sets.

Also, FULLTEXT natural language search does bizarre things on tables with less than a couple of hundred rows. So don't be discouraged if your tiny test tables don't seem to do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in your case, the query returned 4 records. In my case, it should return only one record

Comment: If you need to return only the exact number of rows you expected, MySQL's FULLTEXT is not suitable for your application. Read my last two paragraphs.

Comment: If the full-text search is not suitable, can you propose something other?

Comment: I believe  it's suitable for many applications like the one you propose. But it's designed to work in conjunction with a human user. If that doesn't work for you, you probably should use complex WHERE clauses like `WHERE (firstname LIKE '%rick%' OR lastname LIKE '%rick%'`   A more sophisticated search engine is available in Sphinx (https://sphinxsearch.com/)  but that too requires a human to choose the best results.